# duplicate symbols for architecture i386 - Error during adding custom framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a custom framework into 2 projects but an error occurred.

```
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ApiECV in:
    /Users/kevinmachado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnvDevTestiPad-bvscnxvnzjltpxcxuoomuaqqsxpj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAPI_ECV.a(ApiECV.o)
    /Users/kevinmachado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnvDevTestiPad-bvscnxvnzjltpxcxuoomuaqqsxpj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMKCalendar.a(ApiECV.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ApiECV in:
    /Users/kevinmachado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnvDevTestiPad-bvscnxvnzjltpxcxuoomuaqqsxpj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAPI_ECV.a(ApiECV.o)
    /Users/kevinmachado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnvDevTestiPad-bvscnxvnzjltpxcxuoomuaqqsxpj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMKCalendar.a(ApiECV.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think this error is coming because I try to compile twice my custom framework.

I have 3 projects on my workspace. `API_ECV` and `iPadTest` are both calling `MKCalendar` as *framework*

You can take a look here :
[image: Projet tree]

`iPadTest` build phase :
[image: iPadTest build Phase]

`API_ECV` build phase :
[image: API_ECV build Phase]

If I delete the *link* in `API_ECV` no error occurred but I can't use `MKCalendar framework`

Anyone have an idea ? Can I link my custom framework without compiling it twice ?

Thx ;)

Comment: Can you check do you have selected armv7s? build settings -> architecture

Comment: Yes, armv7s is selected in all projects

Comment: can you remove and try it once?

Comment: No change.. :/ But now I have a new error, I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. For a simple dependency like yours, just remove `libMKCalendar.a` from either `iPadTest` or `API_ECV`. Then it will be linked exactly once. (You would need to specify path to its headers were the compiler to have problems).
2. If you have more complicated dependencies, just turn `MKCalendar` into a framework, then it can be intelligently reused by different targets. iOS frameworks are available if you use Xcode 6 beta.

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted, I guess that:

- API_ECV linked from MKCalendar
- API_ECV linked from iPadTest
- MKCalendar linked from iPadTest

So here is where your duplicate comes from, API_ECV twice from direct link **and** MKCalendar link.
Two possible solutions:

- Don't link it from iPadTest, relying on MKCalendar to provide it
- Mark it as "Optional" in MKCalendar (Where is is mentioned "Required")